# I am not able to save the changes in tnsnames.ora file

Tags: windows-7, file-permissions, oracle-11g

I am trying to save the `tnsnames.ora` file, but couldn't. It showed access denied. Any one have any idea regarding this? Currently I am using Oracle 11g on Windows 7

Comment: don't you get a UAC prompt?

Comment: What I have done with errors like this.  and I sometimes run into it with tnsnames.ora or web.config or similar.  save your edits to your desktop and then drag and drop it into the appropriate directory.

Answer (score 5):

In most case this means that you want to save the file at a location where you need administrator permissions to do so. There are two possible solutions for this:

1. Store the file somewhere else where you don't need admin permission (like own documents or something like that).
2. Start the program you use to save the file as Administrator (if you have the permission to do so) and save the file anywhere you want. !Caution! If you save the file this way, you are able to overwrite other files with the same name even if they are critical and you are able to store the file in locations where the normal user can't read it.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue with the `hosts` file, which I was trying to edit using notepad.
You can only edit and save this file as Administrator, so try this:

Go to `Start > All Programs > Accessories`, right click `Notepad` and then click `Run as Administrator` (might prompt for password).
Then do `File > Open` and navigate to the `tnsnames.ora` file.

Make the changes then it should allow you to save (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>).

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem and I found out that the folder where this file was in had a read-only flag (the read-only flag re-appeared every time no matter what I did). Sharing out a folder to network users (and then stopping sharing after that) fixed the issue and I was able to save the file.